# Dynamic JQuery mobile popup with Ajax JSON

Tags: json, jquery, jquery-mobile, dynamic

I have an MVC 4 mobile website.  The first page has a popup that needs to display a large amount of text coming from the controller via an AJAX request.

In the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetLongText()
{
    return Json(OurState.GetLongText);
}
```

Which will just return what is in the error function on the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/TyhnV/28/

The first click of the button will show the popup off to the side, the second click will properly center it to the window.
I need to know how to create the popup dynamically so that the first click of the button will get the right window position for the popup, rather than misplacing it because of the size of the text being placed in it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/TyhnV/41/ based on your demo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a little basic tutorial on how to create a popup dynamically on the fly.

```
// close button
var closeBtn = $('<a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>').button();

// text you get from Ajax
var content = "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing. Morbi convallis sem et dui sollicitudin tincidunt.</p>";

// Popup body - set width is optional - append button and Ajax msg
var popup = $("<div/>", {
    "data-role": "popup"
}).css({
    "width": "150px"
}).append(closeBtn).append(content);

// Append it to active page
$(".ui-page-active").append(popup);

// Create it and add listener to delete it once it's closed
// add listener to change its' position if you want
$("[data-role=popup]").on("popupafterclose", function () {
    $(this).remove();
}).on("popupafteropen", function () {
    $(this).popup("reposition", {
        "positionTo": "window"
        /* or set custom position */
        x: 150,
        y: 200
    });
// enhance popup and open it
}).popup().popup("open");
```

You don't need to use `.trigger("create")` because every single element is enhanced ahead. There are other advanced options to manipulate popup widget.

```
$(".selector").popup({
    "theme" : "a",
    "overlayTheme" : "e",
    "history" : false,
    "dismissible" : false,
    "transition" : "fade"
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/kgZcr/)**