# jquery mobile only one popup for many list items

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

I have the following code for a jquery mobile list view with popup of options for each list item.

Would like to have only one popup where the id of the link is passed to it instead of a new popuo for each list item. How can one pass the id into the popup?

```
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
             <h1>My page</h1> 
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="#thepopup" id="5" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop"><h2>Item 1</h2></a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#purchase" id="6" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop"><h2>Item 2</h2></a>
            <p>Item 2 description</p></a>

                </li>
            </ul>
            <div data-role="popup" id="thepopup">
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li><a href="view.php?id=5">View details</a></li> 
HERE THE "5" SHOULD BE THE ID OF THE ITEM CLICKED ABOVE
                    <li><a href="edit.php?id=5">Edit</a></li>
                    <li><a data-rel="back" href="#">Cancel</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you can create popups dynamically. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20505799/1771795

Comment: is there a way to simply pass an id to a hardwired popup?

Comment: sure it's possible. `$(this).attr("id")` on click event will save id of clicked button.

Comment: right but how do you modify the links of the hardwired popup?

Comment: you want to change `href="view.php?id=` in popup listview?

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/G24HR/ I removed `rel=popup` from both links and moved popup div outside content div. It should be a direct child of page div.

Comment: wow thanks alot. does it also change edit.php?id= to view.php?id=

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43066/discussion-between-omar-and-ray-s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, *popup* div should be a direct child of *page* div.

Secondly, you can call *popup* programmatically upon clicking a list item. Once clicked, retrieve *id* of clicked item and add it to links in popup, then open it.

```
$("li a").on("click", function (e) {

    // retrieve id
    var item_id = $(this).attr("id");

    // update links in popup with id retrieved
    // exclude cancel button [data-rel=back]
    $("#thepopup li a:not(:jqmData(rel=back))").each(function () {
        var current = $(this).attr("href").split("=");
        var href = current[0] + "=" + item_id;
        $(this).attr("href", href);
    });

    // open popup with desired transition
    $("#thepopup").popup("open", {
        "transition": "pop"
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/G24HR/)**