# JQueryMobile Pass PHP GET variables to a panel or popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a web app with MySQL, php5 and jQuery Mobile.

One thing I don't know how to do is for example I have a ListView of Products, and each product has an ID.

So on classic PHP, I would put a delete button to each product and the link will be something like:

```
echo "delete.php?itemid=".$varitemid;
```

Now What I'm doing is for each product I have a Options button, and this button opens a popup that has two buttons: edit and delete. Now the link for the delete button will be the previous `echo "delete.php?itemid=".$varitemid;`

But my question is, How do I pass `$varitem` to the popup or to a panel of jQuery Mobile? Can it be on the same php file or do I have to use a different one?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549242/jquery-mobile-only-one-popup-for-many-list-items/20550391#20550391

Comment: Thanks Omar! this is good to update the links of the popup. However, I also need to have the ItemID in a PHP variable, so I can show the info about the item that is going to be deleted. I want to show a message that says "Are you sure you want to delete".$ItemID.$ItemName. If I could have ItemID in a PHP variable, I can easily do this.

Comment: hmmm, I'm not a PHP guy, but you could _echo_ it as a value in a hidden _input_ and retrieve it. bad idea, isn't?